# sum of products of couples in a list

Tags: python, list, sum, product, brute-force

I want to find out the sum of products of couples in a list.
For example a list is given `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. What I want to get is answer = `1*2 + 1*3 + 1*4 + 2*3 + 2*4 + 3*4`.

I do it using brute-force, it gives me the time-out error for very large lists. 
I want an efficient way to do this. Kindly tell me, how can I do this?

Here is my code, this is working but i need more efficient one:

```
def proSum(list):
    count  = 0
    for i in range(len(list)- 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(list)):
            count +=  list[i] * list[j]
    return count
```

Comment: You want product of adjacent pairs (with wrapparound for last)?

Comment: Please add your current code to the question

Comment: in this example, i take two elements as pairs, but it can be more and I've to find all possible products and then the sum

Comment: Without seeing your current code, it's not at all clear why you'd get a timeout error.  The "obvious" brute force shouldn't run into timeout errors.

Comment: ah - if you're dealing with more products, that could cause issues.  But just these adjacent pairs isn't a problem.  So we need a clearer question to know what the issue could be.

Comment: what if i am given an integer instead of the list and I've to do the same process with range(1, integer+1). Should I use a list = range(1, Integer + 1) or I can do something more efficient.

Comment: @lavee_singh, if you edit or change your question with fundamental differences, it'd be great if you put **EDITED/UPDATED** keywords and leave the original requirements intact.

Comment: @Anzel you can get down vote to this question and vote to close

Comment: @KasraAD, I would love to, apart from OP edited his question without proper trace, the question itself is rather legitimate.

Comment: @Anzel legitimate doesn't mean here ! i think its an insult , when some body edit his question completely after that many people gave him an answer .

Comment: @KasraAD, you're right, we're here intended to help, not being insulted.

Comment: @lavee_singh: I realize that you probably don't care, but please do accept one of the answers - people put a lot of effort here.

Comment: I do accept. But I don't know how to show that I've accepted, and I am totally new so I will take my time to learn things. And sorry for the inconvenience due to the change!

Comment: Lavee Singh take a look at my answer below, only four lines.

Answer (score 6):

Here it is:

```
In [1]: def prodsum(xs):
   ...:     return (sum(xs)**2 - sum(x*x for x in xs)) / 2
   ...: 

In [2]: prodsum([1, 2, 3, 4]) == 1*2 + 1*3 + 1*4 + 2*3 + 2*4 + 3*4
Out[2]: True
```

Let `xs = a1, a2, .., an`, then

`(a1+a2+...+an)^2 = 2(a1a2+a1a3+...+an-1an) + (a1^2+...+an^2)`

So we have

`a1a2+...+an-1an = {(a1+a2+...+an)^2 - (a1^2+...+an^2)}/2`

---

**Compare the performance of @georg's method and mine**

The result and the test codes as following(The less time used is better):
[image]

```
In [1]: import timeit

In [2]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [3]: def eastsunMethod(xs):
   ...:     return (sum(xs)**2 - sum(x*x for x in xs)) / 2
   ...: 

In [4]: def georgMethod(given):
   ...:     sum = 0
   ...:     res = 0
   ...:     cur = len(given) - 1
   ...: 
   ...:     while cur >= 0:
   ...:         res += given[cur] * sum
   ...:         sum += given[cur]
   ...:         cur -= 1
   ...:     return res
   ...: 

In [5]: sizes = range(24)

In [6]: esTimes, ggTimes = [], []

In [7]: for s in sizes:
   ...:     t1 = timeit.Timer('eastsunMethod(xs)', 'from __main__ import eastsunMethod;xs=range(2**%d)' % s)
   ...:     t2 = timeit.Timer('georgMethod(xs)', 'from __main__ import georgMethod;xs=range(2**%d)' % s)
   ...:     esTimes.append(t1.timeit(8))
   ...:     ggTimes.append(t2.timeit(8))

In [8]: fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 6));lines = ax.plot(sizes, esTimes, 'r', sizes, ggTimes);ax.legend(lines, ['Eastsun', 'georg'], loc='center');ax.set_xlabel('size');ax.set_ylabel('time');ax.set_xlim([0, 23])
```

Comment: Good maths, but since since OP's talking about "very large" lists, I guess the iterative approach will perform better. But nice...

Comment: For very large lists, you can probably benefit from numpy, and use `(np.sum(xs)**2 - np.sum(x**2)) / 2`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to generate unique pairs:

```
# gives [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
unique_pairs = list(itertools.combinations([1, 2, 3, 4], 2))
```

Then use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to get the product of each pair:

```
products = [x*y for x, y in unique_pairs] # => [2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12]
```

Then use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) to add up your products:

```
answer = sum(products) # => 35
```

This can be all wrapped up in a one-liner like so:

```
answer = sum(x*y for x,y in itertools.combinations([1, 2, 3, 4], 2))
```

In making it a one-liner the result of `combinations` is used without casting to a `list`.  Also, the brackets around the list comprehension are discarded, transforming it [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression).

**Note**:  [Eastsun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28146877/1322401) and [georg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28146557/1322401) use much better algorithms and will easily outpreform my answer for large lists.

Comment: Downvoter, I would appreciate an explanatory comment.  Thanks!

Comment: I think all of us got a -ve out of the blue just like how OP changed his question. Honestly I think your answer is the most thoroughly explained +1 to you.

Comment: Apologize for the sudden change, I'd not think it could create clash!

Comment: Nice, I didn't know there was a `combinations` method so I used `permutations` below instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: actually [@Eastsun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28146877/989121) is better.

Here's another, more "algorithmical" way to deal with that. Observe that given

> a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub>

the desired sum is (due to the distributive law)

> a<sub>0</sub> (a<sub>1</sub> +  a<sub>2</sub> + ... + a<sub>n</sub>) 
>   + a<sub>1</sub> (a<sub>2</sub> +  a<sub>3</sub> + ... + a<sub>n</sub>) 
>   + ...
>   + a<sub>n-2</sub> (a<sub>n-1</sub> +  a<sub>n</sub>) 
>   + a<sub>n-1</sub> a<sub>n</sub>

which leads to the following algorithm:

- let `sum` be 0 and `current` be the last element
- on each step

  - multiply `sum` and `current` and add to the result
  - add `current` to `sum`
  - let `current` be the previous of `current`

In python:

```
sum = 0
res = 0
cur = len(given) - 1

while cur >= 0:
    res += given[cur] * sum
    sum += given[cur]
    cur -= 1

print res
```

Comment: This is a really great answer, but please please please consider not using the name `sum` as it hides the built-in function.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: to play the devil's advocate for a moment, there's a bit too much hype about this "don't shadow builtins" issue. First, the code is supposed to be inside a small, standalone function, so it doesn't affect other `sum`s in the program in any way. Second, IMO, python's usage of globals is one of the faults of the language. GvR somehow managed to reserve all "cool" names for his own use! Especially I do hate how my IDE highlights `id` each time (which is essential in any DB-related code), and I have never used python's `id()` a single time in my life!

Answer (score 0):

With no external library, you can use `map` and `lambda` to calculate `*` pairwise, and then `sum` everything up

```
l=[1, 2, 3, 4]
sum(map(lambda x,y:x*y, l, l[1:]+[l[0]]))
```

But since you are dealing with big data, I suggest you use numpy.

```
import numpy as np

l = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

print sum(l*np.roll(l, 1))
# 24
```

EDIT: to keep up with the updated question of OP

```
import numpy as np

l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
sums = 0
while l:
    sums+=sum(l.pop(0)*np.array(l))

print sums
#35
```

So what it does is taking out the first element of list and `*` with the rest. Repeating until there is nothing to take out from the list.

Comment: The result should not be 24, it should be 35.

Comment: this is really good, but doesn't meet my needs, please review the question and what if i am given an integer instead of the list and I've to do the same process with range(1, integer+1). Should I use a list = range(1, Integer + 1) or I can do something more efficient

Comment: @howaboutNO, The OP has just changed the question! Look around you!

Comment: @lavee_singh, I edited to your new requirement. You can check if it working. If you were given an `interger`, put it in a list.

Comment: @lavee_singh, like this `if type(input)==int: input=[input]`

Comment: The result is needed to 35 instead of 24, thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

def sumOfProductsOfCouples(l):
  return sum(l[i-1] * l[i] for i, n in enumerate(l))

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import combinations
l=[1, 2, 3, 4]
cnt=0
for x in combinations(l,2):
    cnt+=x[0]*x[1]
print (cnt)
```

Output;

```
>>> 
35
>>>
```

`combinations()` will give your pairs like you want. Then do your calculates.

**Debug it like**;

```
l=[1, 2, 3, 4]
for x in combinations(l,2):
    print (x)

>>> 
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(3, 4)
>>>
```

See that your pairs are here. Actually you will find the sum of this `combinations pairs.`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `permutations` method from the `itertools` module:

```
from itertools import *

p = permutations([1, 2, 3, 4], 2) # generate permutations of two
p = [frozenset(sorted(i)) for i in p] # sort items and cast 
p = [list(i) for i in set(p)] # remove duplicates, back to lists

total = sum([i[0] * i[1] for i in p]) # 35 your final answer
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use map, sum functions.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> sum(map(sum, [map(lambda e: e*k, l) for k, l in zip(a, (a[start:] for start, _ in enumerate(a, start=1) if start < len(a)))]))
35
```

Dividing above expression in parts,

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> c = (a[start:] for start, _ in enumerate(a, start=1) if start < len(a))
>>> sum(map(sum, [map(lambda e: e*k, l) for k, l in zip(a, c)]))
35
```